# Calculate number of days from bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm using bootstrap jquery daterangepicker. My intention is to find the number of days between 2 dates.
In my HTML I'm using 2 input fields as below

```html
<div class="col-12 form-group has-feedback">
    <label>From <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="fromdate" 
        placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="fromdate">
</div>
<div class="col-12 form-group has-feedback">
    <label>To <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="todate" 
        placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" name="todate">
</div>
```

Now I need to auto populate the number of days when user select the from date and to date to the below input value

```html
<div class="col-12 form-group has-feedback">
    <label>Number of days <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" name="numberdays" 
        id="numberdays" disabled>
</div>
```

I have been referring the bootstrap jquery daterangepicker forum and other internet sources for a solution but unfortunate. Appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really looks like *[bootstrap date range picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)* works well with just one input for the range, rather than what you had there - an input for from date and another input for to date.

## Just 1 input for the date range

If you can change your inputs to just one single input for the date range

```html
<div class="col-12 form-group has-feedback">
    <label>From <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="daterange" 
        name="daterange">
</div>
```

Then you can calculate the day difference very easily after initializing the range input with *bootstrap date range picker*:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#daterange').daterangepicker();

    $('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        // picker.startDate and picker.endDate are already Moment.js objects.
        // You can use diff() method to calculate the day difference.
        $('#numberdays').val(picker.endDate.diff(picker.startDate, "days"));
    });
});
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ec2L749p/10/

[image]

## If you have to have start and end date input

I would suggest to just use *[jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)* for that because *bootstrap date ranger picker* doesn't work that well with multiple date inputs.

To use *jquery datepicker*, remember to include *jquery* as well as *jquery-ui* (also its css too).

You can make them as date range picker by:

```js
$(function() {
    let $fromDate = $('#fromdate'),
        $toDate = $('#todate');

    $fromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());
    });

    $toDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());
    });;
});
```

The last thing you need to do is just to have a function to calculate the date difference on their change event:

```js
$(function() {
    let $fromDate = $('#fromdate'),
        $toDate = $('#todate'),
        $numberDays = $('#numberdays');

    $fromDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());

        $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($toDate.val(), $(this).val()));
    });

    $toDate.datepicker().on('change', function(){
        $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());

        $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($(this).val(), $fromDate.val()));
    });

    function calculateDateDiff(endDate, startDate) {
        if (endDate && startDate) {
            let e = moment(endDate),
                s = moment(startDate);

            return e.diff(s, "days");
        }

        return null;
    }
});
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ec2L749p/20/

[image]

## Omit weekends

I will use the demo using *jquery datepicker* because it supports disabling weekends on the date picker by just setting `beforeShowDay` property:

```js
$fromDate.datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
}).on('change', function(){
    $toDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).val());

    $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($toDate.val(), $(this).val()));
});

$toDate.datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
}).on('change', function(){
    $fromDate.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $(this).val());

    $numberDays.val(calculateDateDiff($(this).val(), $fromDate.val()));
});
```

All weekends on the date picker are disabled:

[image]

And then you need to change the function `calculateDateDiff()` to ignore the weekends while doing the calculation. Here I am adding a third parameter called `noWeekends` to indicate whether we want the calculation to ignore weekends or not:

```js
function calculateDateDiff(endDate, startDate, noWeekends) {
    if (endDate && startDate) {
        let e = moment(endDate),
            s = moment(startDate);

        if (!noWeekends) {
            return e.diff(s, "days");
        }

        let count = 0;
        for(let m = s; m.isBefore(e); m.add(1, 'days')) {
            if (m.isoWeekday() !== 6 && m.isoWeekday() !== 7) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ec2L749p/32/

## Friendly Reminder

If you intend to post `numberdays` input back to the server, setting it as `disabled` won't work. You might consider setting it as `readonly`.

Comment: Works Awsome. Thanks a ton and appreciate your suggestions. Would like to add an additional question. How to omit the holidays(weekdays) from the count?

Comment: You mean how to omit weekends from the count?

Comment: Yes. I need to omit the weekends

Comment: Thank you. but how to do for jquery daterangepicker

Comment: @theveil: the function to calculate the diff would be the same. It's just that daterangepicker doesn't have options for you to disable weekends, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) is your best friend when it comes to handle date and time:

```
var a = moment($('#fromdate').val());
var b = moment($('#todate').val());
$('#numberdays').val(a.diff(b, 'days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
$('input[name="fromdate"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        if($('input[name="todate"]').val() != ''){
        var a = moment($('input[name="fromdate"]').val());
        var b = moment($('input[name="todate"]').val());
        $('#numberdays').val(b.diff(a, 'days'));
    }
});

 $('input[name="todate"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        var a = moment($('input[name="fromdate"]').val());
        var b = moment($('input[name="todate"]').val());
        $('#numberdays').val(b.diff(a, 'days'));
});
```